# C# Filter out the process list

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, process

I would like to filter out the list of processes. By downloading processes I would like to eliminate system processes. I know how to get a list of processes but nowhere can I find a method to check to which user the process belongs

It's my code :

```
    public static List<string> GetRunningProcess(bool WithoutSystemProcess = false)
    {
        var Proc = Process.GetProcesses();
        List<string> ProcNameList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var i in Proc)
        {
            if (WithoutSystemProcess)
            {
                //ToDo
            }
            else
                ProcNameList.Add(i.ProcessName);
        }
        return ProcNameList;
    }
```

Comment: sab669's comment shows it is definitely a duplicate, but I want to suggest a better structuring of your function. `if (WithoutSystemProcess) { foreach (var p in Proc) { // ToDo } } else { ProcNameList = Proc.Select(p => p.ProcessName).ToList(); }` This takes the if statement out of the foreach loop. It only needs to be checked once.

Comment: @MethodMan Thank you but the links provided do not solve my problem. I find field Process.StartInfo.UserName but I get string type value String.Empty

Comment: `to which user the process belongs` - what exactly you mean under this ? in all case you need open process token and query information from it

Comment: @RbMm Thanks ! Are you able to show me a simple query to get user that has launched a process such as 'SYSTEM' , 'Tom' 

 string query = "Select * From Win32_Process Where UserNameOfProc <> 'SYSTEM' ";

Comment: I was able to use the accepted answer in sab669's link to get the process names. It was slow and some processes didn't have owners, but many showed the username.

Comment: @Jakop - i not write on c# and not use so not effective wmi. i be call *OpenProcess*, than *OpenProcessToken*, then *GetTokenInformation* with *TokenUser* information-class. and finaly convert user *SID* to name by *LookupAccountSid*